# Multiple levels of encryption

Tags: encryption, keys, access-control

Is it feasible to have data encrypted at different levels of hierarchy

I'd like to encrypt an xml database (such as used in [www.keepass.info](http://www.keepass.info)) whereby two or more keys can exist. For example:

1. <kbd>Key #1</kbd> decrypts the entire database file
2. <kbd>Key #2</kbd> decrypts a subset of the database file

Is this technically possible/recommended? The reason I'm looking is that I currently use keepass for myself and I repeatedly get family members saying that they've forgotten their password and do I know what it is...so I would like them all stored in a master database file that we can keep on our home network storage

Comment: Why don't your family members create their own keepass database? Then they can give you their keepass password, which you store in your own database.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I had been wondering about that - although it would be easier to keep it organise as I'm the only one entering/maintaining them - so I would rather have a group for each person that I can oversee with my "master" account rather than having to get everyones passwords/keyfiles and switching between them when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can create a symmetric key per entry. You can then wrap that key with any key (of any person) you want and store the wrapped keys with each entry.

I strongly suspect that doing so within keypass is not possible.